# Tracking login attempts using cookies PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have been given a homework assignment where I need to create a captcha to login to a 'comments' section.

I have the captcha working fine, no problem. We are also tasked with keeping count of failed attempts at the captcha. No problem.

Here IS my problem. We are told that the user is allowed to try as many times as he or she wishes, however, if they fail 5 times within a thirty second limit, they are locked out for three minutes.

I understand how to track 5 missed attempts, but how would you track the timing on this one? If the user tried 4 times in 15 seconds, and then waited for a minute (or less, obviously), the clock is reset, and they have 5 more tries. Furthermore, if they tried twice and waited 30 seconds, the attempts would try again.

Do I need to set a time cookie, a secondary count cookie (to go along with the original count cookie), and track the start of the secondary counter and just see if that counter increments to 5? How would you do this?

EDIT:

Have to apologize, apparently I was not completely clear on my situation. In this homework assignment, it is strictly stipulated we must use cookies to accomplish this task. We are not looking at best practice or security at this point, the instructor simply wants us to be comfortable with cookies. Unfortunately, session is not an option for me, I must use cookies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you've tagged this as PHP, simply start a session with `session_start()`. That gives each user a unique ID via a cookie, and you can store their login attempts in the `$_SESSION` array on the server. At each login attempt, you can check the recorded attempts stored in the session and see if they exceed the allowable attempt rate.

Of course, the usual warnings hold: On a real security system, an attacker would be highly unlikely to maintain that session cookie over their many attempts - they'd ignore it, forcing a new blank session to be created each time.

Comment: We should be teaching best practices here, yes?  Given that the client can reset that session by dumping their cookies, this isn't a good idea at all.

Comment: I see that.  I wouldn't be a bit surprised though to see someone come along and implement what you have suggested, despite your warning, simply because it's "easier".  Oh well, I guess that is their problem.

Comment: In my answer I included a method for stopping people from bypassing the security by dumping their cookies.

Comment: Given the usual warnings, what would be the alternatives?

Comment: There aren't any 100% reliable methods. The web's fundamentally stateless, and the methods used to add statefulness all have plusses/minuses. Cookies can simply be ignored. Blocking by ip harms those who are behind the same proxies/nat gateways as attackers, etc... At some point you have to draw a line in the sand and say "we're prepared to cause this much trouble in exchange for this much benefit/gain".

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't do this in cookies at all!  Users can circumvent this easily, making your system quite insecure.

You should log every login attempt in a database.  Then, just query for attempts made within your specified time period when they try to login.  If they have already tried too often, don't let them in.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is homework, no code for you!

At a high level, all you need to do is to store the timestamps instead of the "count". Then on each request you can toss away timestamps older than 30 seconds and count the rest.

Answer (score 1):

The issue of protecting your system from a malicious user should be handled server-side. You could use a combination of IP and username attempting to login to build a unique identifier for that individual. If that combination of credentials attempt to force a login, block that individual for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement the spec as it is and would not try to interpret it. It would increase the complexity of the problem.

In order to implement I suggest use sessions, or server side logs instead of handling hand made cookies. you could keep the timing of each login attempt for the user, before each authentication check the last 5 attempts. if the first value time is less than thirty seconds, alert the user and disable the login form for 5 minutes. you could store the time of unlocking the form in the user session (by adding the waiting seconds to the time of the last failed attempt), and so every request for the login form would failed if the time of the server is less than the unlock time. When the form is unlocked, remove the unlock timestamp on the user session, and re-enable the form.

Answer (score 0):

I would log each failed attempt as an array in the session.

Here is some code and pseudo-code.

```
<?
// Check if they are locked out.
if ($_SESSION['lockedOutTime'] < (time() - (3*60))) {

    // they are locked out; don't attempt login

    // notify them that they are still locked out



// If they aren't locked out, allow them to attemp the login
} else {

    // Attempt login
    // ...

    // if failed... log it
    $_SESSION['failedLoginAttempts'][] = time();

    $thirtySecondsAgo = time();
    $failedAttemptsInTheLastThirtySeconds = 0;


    // count failed login attempts in the last 30 seconds
    foreach ($_SESSION['failedLoginAttempts'] as $failedAttempTime) {

        if ($failedAttempTime >= $thirtySecondsAgo) {

            $failedAttemptsInTheLastThirtySeconds++;

        }

    }

    // Check if they are over the limit
    if ($failedAttemptsInTheLastThirtySeconds >= 5) {

        // lock em out
        $_SESSION['lockedOutTime'] = time();

        // Notify user they have been locked out
        // ...

    }



}

?>
```